# ASP.NET 32-bit machine compiled now trying to run on 64-bit machine

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have an ASP.NET app that was compiled on a 32-bit machine.  There are many different assemblies that are referenced.  I opened the web site's main dll with ILDASM and looked at the .corflags.  It stated it was ILONLY.  However, when I run the web site locally on the 64-bit machine (Windows XP Pro 64-bit), I get "is not a valid Win32 applciation".  Shouldn't the app run as 64-bit since it was compiled with "AnyCPU"?  How can I get this to work?  I am using .NET 3.5.  I want the app to run as 64-bit, not 32-bit.

Comment: Could you define "when I run the web site locally", i.e. How do you receive the "not a valid Win32 application" message - is that in the Event Log?

Comment: Are all referenced assemblies AnyCPU as well? You cannot load any 32 bit assemblies in a 64 bit app.

Comment: To run locally (all files are on my machine), I run http://localhost/myapp/mydefaultpage.aspx

Comment: All assemblies are set to AnyCPU

Comment: So, where do you see the "Not a valid Win32 application" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some of your dlls are not compiled as AnyCPU.

Use the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from sysinternals to locate it and fix it / change it.

With the Process monitor you can see where its fail to load a dll.

Also you can use the [dependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) after you locate some of your problematic dll, to see more info on the dll that are not loaded.

Hope this help.